# How do I make multiple click responsive canvases in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The code below is supposed to create 10x10 colored boxes at the tooltip in the canvas it is within, alternating between reddish and bluish on a gray background.  I want each canvas to respond to the mouse only when it is within the canvas.  The code below makes 4 square gray canvases, but when the mouse is over the leftmost one, colored boxes appear in the rightmost canvas.  No other canvases work.

So here are my two questions.

1. Why is only one canvas active?
2. Why do boxes appear on the wrong canvas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="c0" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c1" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c3" width="201" height="201"></canvas>

<script>
var colorno = ["#F77", "#077"];
var the = { 'c0': {}, 'c1': {}, 'c2': {}, 'c3': {} };
var box = 10;
var workings = function(name) {
    instance = the[name];
    instance.name = name;
    canvas = instance.canvas = document.getElementById(instance.name);
    instance.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    instance.index = 0;
    instance.context.fillStyle = "#777";
    instance.context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    scale = (canvas.width - box) / canvas.width;
    canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        instance.context.fillStyle = colorno[++instance.index&1];
        instance.context.fillRect(scale*e.x-box, scale*e.y-box, box, box);
    }, true);
};
for (var key in the) workings(key);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't declare the variable `instance`, causing it to be defined in the global scope. `instance` keeps getting overwrote by your `for` loop and therefore in all 4 handlers, the `instance` variables are all pointing to the same object. Correctly declaring a variable in a closure is very important.

```
var instance = value;      // declare function-scoped variable
let instance = value;      // declare block-scoped variable
function workings(args){}  // declare a function
```

Here is a version of your code that has been fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="c0" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c1" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="201" height="201"></canvas>
<canvas id="c3" width="201" height="201"></canvas>

<script>
var colorno = ["#F77", "#077"];
var the = { 'c0': {}, 'c1': {}, 'c2': {}, 'c3': {} };
var box = 10;

// declare function
function workings(name) {
    // declare variables
    var instance = the[name];
    var canvas = instance.canvas = document.getElementById(name);
    // assign values
    instance.name = name;
    instance.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    instance.index = 0;
    instance.context.fillStyle = "#777";
    instance.context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // attach click listener
    canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        instance.context.fillStyle = colorno[++instance.index&1];
        instance.context.fillRect(
          // calculate correct coordinates
          e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft - box / 2,
          e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop - box / 2, 
          box, box);
    }, true);
};

// invoke function
for (var key in the) workings(key);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Your explanation was nicely brief and clear.  Thank you.